# How to get rid of black overlay on mesh

Tags: rendering, mesh

I don't know how to delete this black lines on line mesh (only can see them in material preview and rendered mode, both eevee and cycles):

[image: The problem]

eevee:

[image: eevee]

cycles:

[image: cycles]

Comment: Does this happen when you go to *Edit Preferences > Viewport > Quality*and enable Anti Aliasing?

Comment: Yes, Anti Aliasing is enabled (8 samples)

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: Sure, here it is:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DZ3qXvzcBXevDkel_lW3zo3TolMXWul7?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI, i included a link in that last comment, that is usually the best place for sharing blend files on this platform. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have doubled geometry on a lot of these meshes.

Just select all, run Remove Doubles and it seems to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank You a lot, I didn't seen share link

Comment: No worries! Stackoverflow gives you the ability to put a link inside text by writing it like this: [what I want the person to read]\(www.the-link-they-can-click-on-goes-here.com). Helps to save space and make the comments more readable.